X11/Xlib - how to intercept minimizing/restoring a window
I can check if a window is minimized when handling PropertyNotify event using _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN atom. Here is an example. That is too late in my case. I would like to intercept minimize/restore action - just after an user clicks minimize button or restore a window. How to achieve it ? Does exists any event which notifies about such actions ?

No way to do that if you are not writing window manager. Because window manager will hide window while it receive _NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN PropertyNotify without sending any *request event. So you no chance to intercept it.
